# Game lags near display list data

Tags: java, opengl

I have a chunk of cubes that is generated using a display list, and ever time I come near it, the frame rate drops significantly. Why is this? Here's some code:

```
public class Chunk implements GameObject {

private int sx, sy, sz, lx, ly, lz, vertID;

private Tile[][][] tiles;

public Chunk(int sx, int sy, int sz) {
    this.sx = sx;
    this.sy = sy;
    this.sz = sz;
    this.lx = sx + 16;
    this.ly = sy + 16;
    this.lz = sz + 16;

    init();
}

@Override
public void init() {
    this.tiles = new Tile[lx][ly][lz];

    vertID = glGenLists(1);

    glNewList(vertID, GL_COMPILE);
    for (int x = sx; x < lx; x++) {
        for (int y = sy; y < ly; y++) {
            for (int z = sz; z < lz; z++) {
                tiles[x][y][z] = new Tile("grass.jpg");
            }
        }
    }
    glEndList();
}

public void rebuild() {
    glNewList(vertID, GL_COMPILE);
    for (int x = sx; x < lx; x++) {
        for (int y = sy; y < ly; y++) {
            for (int z = sz; z < lz; z++) {
                tiles[x][y][z].getVertices(x, y, z, 16);
            }
        }
    }
    glEndList();
}

@Override
public void update() {
}

@Override
public void render() {
    glCallList(vertID);
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
}
```

}

Comment: Do you tried to use some Java profiler tool?

Comment: You should use VAOs and/or VBOs, don't use Display List if you want to render huge amount of vertices.

Comment: Minecraft does it, why can't I?

Comment: @opiop65: I'm pretty sure Minecraft doesn't use display lists.

Comment: @datenwolf Actually Minecraft does use Display Lists, though don't ask me why.

Comment: @opiop65 Minecraft uses a lot of deprecated code, which you should do. It's much better to use new methods of doing things, as of using VAOs with VBOs.

Comment: Exactly, so why should I have to use VBOs? I asked a question, I know what VBOs are. I've used them. I wanted to try to create a minecraft esque engine, so please. My question is still unanswered.

Comment: @datenwolf Just look it up, and apparently Minecraft have switched to VAOs in never versions. Though before it used Display Lists.

Comment: @opiop65 Read the comment I just wrote to datenwolf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies probably herein:

```
glNewList(vertID, GL_COMPILE);
for (int x = sx; x < lx; x++) {
    for (int y = sy; y < ly; y++) {
        for (int z = sz; z < lz; z++) {
            tiles[x][y][z] = new Tile("grass.jpg");
        }
    }
}
glEndList();
```

If I had to make an educated guess your `Tile` class generate and initialiizes a texture. Well, you see, display lists don't just take on geometry and drawing calls. They also encapsulate the creation and setting of texture data. Before OpenGL-1.1 (i.e. OpenGL-1.0) there were no texture objects (`glGenTextures`, `glBindTexture`) and you used display lists as a drop in replacement for that. And that little anachronism is still present today in all compatibility OpenGL profiles. That's also why Windows calls the function to share OpenGL context data `wglShareLists`, although it goes far beyond lists.

To make a long story short, you probably perform a quite expensive operation right in the middle of a display list. No wonder it's slow. But seriously, why are you allocating a new texture for each tile? You should load your images into your textures only once and then only make references to them.

Comment: Actually, that was placeholder code. I wasn't initializing any textures at all, I was just creating the vertices. I removed the glNewList call, and swapped it to an appropriate place, but I still get terrible performance when I create cubes that are 16x16 pixels. 1x1 is fine, but I'm wondering why this is.